# Why when I changed something and reload page my service dont fetch in my angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a method that fetchs customers ID from database and saves it to local storage when user select a customer. But after selection in example if I change something in my code and refresh my page, it doesnt fetch. How can I solve this?

These my code snippets;

```
export class AdminDashboardComponent implements OnInit{

  
  widgets = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  customers: Customer[] = [];
  selectedCustomerId!: string | null;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private dbService: DbService, private customerSelectionService: CustomerSelectionService) { }

  
  ngOnInit() {

    this.selectedCustomerId = localStorage.getItem('selectedCustomerId');

    if (this.selectedCustomerId) {
      this.customerSelectionService.setSelectedCustomerId(this.selectedCustomerId);
    }

    this.fetchCustomers();
  }

  fetchCustomers() {
    this.dbService.selectCustomer().subscribe({
      next: (data: Customer[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.customers = data;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching customers', error);
      },
      complete: () => console.log('Customer fetch completed')      
    });
  }

  onCustomerSelected(event: any) {
   
    const customerId = event.value;
    
    if (customerId !== null && customerId !== undefined) {
     
      this.selectedCustomerId = customerId;
      localStorage.setItem('selectedCustomerId', customerId.toString());
      this.customerSelectionService.setSelectedCustomerId(customerId.toString());
  
      this.dbService.sendCustomerId(customerId).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
          console.log('Customer ID sent to backend successfully:', response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Error sending customer ID to backend:', error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Selected customer ID is null or undefined');
    }
  }
  
  

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    
  }

}
```

> html code for selection ;

```
<div class="selector">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Select Customer</mat-label>
          <mat-select [value]="selectedCustomerId" (selectionChange)="onCustomerSelected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.customer_id">
              {{ customer.customer_name }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

> customer selection service

```
export class CustomerSelectionService {
  private selectedCustomerIdSource = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);
  selectedCustomerId$ = this.selectedCustomerIdSource.asObservable();

  setSelectedCustomerId(customerId: string | null) {
    this.selectedCustomerIdSource.next(customerId);
  }

  
}
```

> service at backend

```
selectCustomer(): Observable<any[]> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl + "/admin-dashboard", httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: If you mean the code in the browser doesn't reflect the code that you changed in your editor, make sure you've disabled browser caching. Open the dev tools, go to the network tab, and select "Disable Cache". Then keep the dev tools open. When you refresh the page, it should refetch the new angular code.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. But no I mean when I changed something in my code, Selected customer dissapears, and also can't fetch customers from database anymore. I need to solve that

Comment: @mbakgor could you check the console if there are any errors?

Comment: Actually I dont have any related error in console. Also I have "Customer fetch completed". from complete: () => console.log('Customer fetch completed'). But customers in selector wont show.

Comment: seems like you should get/set the customerID after fetching the customers, no?  So maybe in the complete => part check localstorage and set.

Answer (score 0):

did I understand correctly? That you receive data from BE but they are not rendered in the template? Which `ChangeDetection` Strategy do you use before initializing the class? If you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, delete it or use detectChanges() after you receive the data